# How to display a progress bar in an arcpy python toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python-toolbox, gui

I'm programming a python toolbox (*.pyt) and want to display a progressbar in arcgis 10.3. I'm using the same piece of code as [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/213743/97126), but I can't see the same dialog box as above. 
I can only see the messages updating in the geoprocessing "results" window. 
I also tried to add my Pyt to the toolbox window, but this didn't solve this issue.

Is this progressor class only working for python script, and not for python toolbox ?

Comment: What value is this setting in your PYT : `canRunInBackground` ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Thank you for taking the new user [tour].  I have added a brief answer explaining how to display that progress dialog, however it's hard to offer any more help without seeing some test code.  Please [edit] your question to include a test PYT as text (not an image) of what you've tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see the progress dialog as seen in the linked Q&A you need to have `self.canRunInBackground = False` set in your PYT code.  This will force your tool to run in the foreground with that dialog showing.

See [Defining a tool in a Python toolbox](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/defining-a-tool-in-a-python-toolbox.htm)

```
class CalculateSinuosity(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "Calculate Sinuosity"
        self.description = "Sinuosity measures the amount that a river meanders within its valley, " + \
                           "calculated by dividing total stream length by valley length."
        self.canRunInBackground = False
```